# css calc function replacement for android

Tags: html, css

I have table, where second column is 120px wide. And I want to first column have width 100% of what left (100%-120px), but on android I can't use `CALC` function. Source: http://caniuse.com/calc

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">data</td>
        <td class="two">data</td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

### CSS:

```
.one { width: calc(100%-120px); }
.two { width: 120px; }
```

### Question:

How to replace `calc(100%-120px)` so it will work on Android?

*Note: ( I don't know width 100% )*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't set a width on `.one`, or set it to `auto`, then set the parent table to `100%`. This will cause the td with `.one` to fill the remaining space of the table.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RFq5G/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">data</td>
        <td class="two">data</td>
    <tr>
<table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.one { width: 100%; }
.two { min-width: 120px; }
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sY9WX/1)</kbd>

Comment: column `.two` only occupies as much spaces as it's content takes up in your example, and not 120px.

Answer (score 1):

calc is now supported by the Android Browser

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc